# Cannot Center Align Header Title in react-native android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, android-studio, react-native, react-redux

Using stack navigation I have defined the header Title by making it a child component as below

> Headertitle.js

```
render(){
   return(
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:RF(3),fontWeight:'bold',color:'#fff'}}>XYZ</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize:RF(3),color:'#fff'}}>ABC</Text>
        </View>
)}
```

> Parent Component using this header

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
              return {
                headerTitle:(<Headertitle/>),
                headerTitleStyle: {flex: 1, textAlign: 'center'},
                headerRight: (
                  <Icon
                    onPress={navigation.getParam('handleLogout')}
                    name="power-off"
                    type="font-awesome"
                    color="#fff"
                     style={{marginRight:20}}
                    size={RF(4)}
                    backgroundColor="#006DB7"
                  />
                ),

                headerLeft:null
              };
            };
```

It works very well in IOS but cannot be center aligned in Android. Please help. Thanx in advance

Comment: use alignSelf: 'center' on header View

Comment: thanx but it didn't worked

Answer (score 5):

there is a new option in navigator

`createStackNavigator(routes, { headerLayoutPreset: 'center' })`

here is pull request: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/4588

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked to add:

```
    marginRight: 'auto',
    marginLeft: 'auto'
```

..
to headerTitleStyle

Answer (score 3):

We can do it by setting the navigation option's [headerTitleAlign](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlealign) property.

```
navigation.setOptions({ 
    headerTitleAlign: 'center'
});
```

Defaults to center on iOS and left on Android.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, here is solution:

```
    headerLeft: (<View></View>),
    headerRight: (<View></View>),
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color : APP_COLORS.primary, 
      display: 'flex',
      flex: 1,
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fontSize: 15,
    }
```

Comment: but headerLeft: (<View></View>) is removing the back button

Comment: this works if header title is a text component, not if its a custom component

Comment: I was actually running into this not working on even simple text. in my case, I have a hamburger button as the `headerLeft`, it forced my title to be off-center. I had to apply `flex:5/6` in addition for textAlign property to affect true centering.